# LEFT JOIN slows performance by about a hundred times

Tags: mysql, left-join

**Query 1 - without LEFT JOIN:**

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(r.id)

FROM requests r

WHERE r.deleted = 0
AND r.req_status_id = 'processed'
```

**Execution time = 0.012 seconds.**

EXPLAIN results:

```
{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "cost_info": {
      "query_cost": "4335.28"
    },
    "table": {
      "table_name": "r",
      "access_type": "ref",
      "possible_keys": [
        "requests_idx55",
        "req_status_id_2",
        "req_status_id"
      ],
      "key": "req_status_id_2",
      "used_key_parts": [
        "deleted",
        "req_status_id"
      ],
      "key_length": "387",
      "ref": [
        "const",
        "const"
      ],
      "rows_examined_per_scan": 17504,
      "rows_produced_per_join": 17504,
      "filtered": "100.00",
      "using_index": true,
      "cost_info": {
        "read_cost": "834.48",
        "eval_cost": "3500.80",
        "prefix_cost": "4335.28",
        "data_read_per_join": "122M"
      },
      "used_columns": [
        "id",
        "req_status_id",
        "deleted"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Table `requests` info:

- ~3 millions records
- column `deleted`: indexed (index name is `requests_idx55`), datatype - bit(1)
- column `req_status_id`: indexed, datatype - varchar(128)
- column `contract_cat_id` : indexed, datatype - int(10) unsigned

**Query 2 - with LEFT JOIN:**

```
SELECT 
   COUNT(r.id)

FROM requests r

LEFT JOIN wt_contracts_cats wcc
ON r.contract_cat_id = wcc.id

WHERE r.deleted = 0
AND r.req_status_id = 'processed'
```

**Execution time = 0.9-1.1 seconds.**

EXPLAIN results:

```
{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "cost_info": {
      "query_cost": "25840.54"
    },
    "nested_loop": [
      {
        "table": {
          "table_name": "r",
          "access_type": "index_merge",
          "possible_keys": [
            "requests_idx55",
            "req_status_id_2",
            "req_status_id"
          ],
          "key": "intersect(req_status_id,requests_idx55)",
          "key_length": "386,1",
          "rows_examined_per_scan": 10125,
          "rows_produced_per_join": 10125,
          "filtered": "100.00",
          "cost_info": {
            "read_cost": "11665.54",
            "eval_cost": "2025.00",
            "prefix_cost": "13690.54",
            "data_read_per_join": "70M"
          },
          "used_columns": [
            "id",
            "req_status_id",
            "contract_cat_id",
            "deleted"
          ],
          "attached_condition": "((`atm`.`r`.`deleted` = 0) and (`atm`.`r`.`req_status_id` = 'processed'))"
        }
      },
      {
        "table": {
          "table_name": "wcc",
          "access_type": "eq_ref",
          "possible_keys": [
            "PRIMARY"
          ],
          "key": "PRIMARY",
          "used_key_parts": [
            "id"
          ],
          "key_length": "4",
          "ref": [
            "atm.r.contract_cat_id"
          ],
          "rows_examined_per_scan": 1,
          "rows_produced_per_join": 10125,
          "filtered": "100.00",
          "using_index": true,
          "cost_info": {
            "read_cost": "10125.00",
            "eval_cost": "2025.00",
            "prefix_cost": "25840.54",
            "data_read_per_join": "15M"
          },
          "used_columns": [
            "id"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Table `wt_contracts_cats` info:

- ~15 000 records
- column `id`: PRIMARY index, datatype - int(10) unsigned

I tried to understand why it works like this, studied the results of EXPLAIN, but could not find any reason for this behavior.

Can anyone explain why does this happen?

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097)--but this post reflects none re performance. [Tips for asking a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271055/3404097) [Asking query performance questions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3034/43932) [ask] [Help]

Comment: Not sure what there is to explain. A left join is always going to impact performance. What are you expecting to happen? See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/nested-loop-joins.html for documentation about nested loop joins, which is what your second query is using.

Comment: @philipxy Is there any way to create a reproducible example with 3 millions records? :)

Comment: Usually, yes. What did your research on doing it show? Also what size reductions can be done & still have the problem? If this is even the code you actually ran--since you didn't give the rest of a [mre] you cut & pasted & updated your big data into & ran & that would also show all indexes etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's reaching into the other table for no good reason.  Why do a `LEFT JOIN` to that other table if you aren't going to use anything from it?

I think the MySQL Optimizer decided that no one would bother doing such a think so it did not bother to Optimizer it out.  (MariaDB *does* have that optimization.)  Furthermore, if that is buried in a `VIEW`, it makes sense that even a careful programmer would sometimes create an unnecessary `LEFT JOIN`.

File a bug report at bugs.mysql.com .